# How to tell if script/asset is loaded by Asynchronous or Deferred in Chrome Network Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, web-performance

Is there any way to tell if a script/asset is loaded asynchronously or loaded deferred from the Google Chrome Browser Network Tools tab?

Comment: @Gaël Métais any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't see dependencies in the critical rendering path in the network tab of Google Chrome.

What you can do is look at the priority of requests (you might have to enable this tab in the network windows -> right click on the tabs). An async request should have a low priority (just like images which are loaded async). Chromes appears to do just that (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408229), it's not super accurate, but might help you.

Answer (score 0):

a script can be loaded inline in HTML or dynamically via a function call.

To know whether a script was inline or not:

1. Disable javascript (dev tools settings -> disable javascript)
2. Look for that script in the source code (right click -> view page source) of the page, if it's not there then it's loaded asynchronously by default.

If it's included in the source code then look for the `async` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

if the async attribute is present, then the script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async